# Is there a way to dump all native memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I built a shared library to get access linux specific system calls from `Java` code through `jni` and got into trouble  that RSS is constantly getting increased.

Is there a way to examine native memory? I tried to take the core dump with gdb:

```
gdb --pid=6385
gdb> gcore
```

But it turned to become 9GB for 400MB RSS. Maybe there is some another simpler way or tool to troubleshoot that?

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The amount of virtual memory (what apps have access to) may be (far) greater than the physical RAM installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C Standard allows implementations to do anything they see fit if an application tries to access memory it doesn't own.  Some implementations designed for low-level programming usefully guarantee that attempts to access storage through a pointer they don't "understand" will be processed "in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment" (typically be treating them as requests to access the underlying hardware addresses.  Some implementations designed for handling security-sensitive applications may usefully prevent attempts to access unowned storage by actively blocking them and "terminating a translation or execution (with a diagnostic message)".  Some may simply do whatever happens to be convenient in any given circumstance.

The authors of the Standard recognized that implementations are used for a variety of purposes, and that treatments that would be suitable for some tasks would be unsuitable for others.  According to the published Rationale, the question of which approach implementations should use for processing actions the Standard regards as "Undefined Behavior" is a "Quality of Implementation" issue, letting the "marketplace" decide how quality implementations intended for various purposes should be expected to behave.